# Initialise elements of a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int freq;
    char val;
} Char; // alias
```

And I need to create a buffer (pointer) to a certain number of `Char` as follows:

```
Char* chars  = calloc(256, sizeof(Char));
```

And I would like to initialize `freq` to `-1` for all `Char` structs in `chars`. Is it possible to do it without a loop?

Comment: `memset`, if you don't mind having `-1` or some other junk in `val`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `val` can be anything provided it's a `char`, of course, but `-1` is not a char, or is it? Actually I was forgetting, when I declare a variable with `char val`, I am declaring a 8 bit signed int, right? Which means that -1 will be considered a `char`, right?

Comment: Anyway, it's a bad idea, as `memset` can fill with byte value only. And in order to fill `int's you will have to assume a specific negative numbers representations, which is not portable.

Comment: @nbro `char` is not guaranteed to be signed, it's implementation defined. It could be unsigned.

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? That's what they're for. Many other languages may have some fancy syntax for specifying the loop in a shorter way, but they all end up looping, and the compiler will do that in whatever way is most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GCC you can do `Char s[256] = {[0 ... 255] = {-1, 0}};`

`{-1, 0}` is the structure initialization

EDIT: You can have a look at this post: 
[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)
It would give great hints :)

Comment: OK, now you are talking... Update: Actually the OP is asking about dynamically allocated array, so it won't work... But it's a good pointer.

Comment: The links gives the function:
`void array_init( void *start, size_t element_size, size_t elements, void *initval ){
  memcpy(        start,              initval, element_size              );
  memcpy( (char*)start+element_size, start,   element_size*(elements-1) );
}`

It can be used to dynamically allocate the array :)